# Not load kartik's select2 as filter in GridView. Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, jquery-select2

I try to filter a column using Select2 Kartik, but nothing appears. The select2 does not load completely. Show the display label as None.

**`/views/user/index.php`**

```php
    'columns' => [
       [
           'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
       ],
       'name',

    /*
       This code not works :(
    */

       [
           'attribute' => 'identification_type',
           'value'=> function($model){
               return Yii::t('app', TYPE_ID[$model->identification_type]);
           },
           'filter' => Select2::widget([
               'model' => $searchModel,
               'attribute' => 'identification_type',
               'data' => Arrai::t('person',TYPE_ID),
               'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
               'hideSearch' => true,
               'options' => [
                   'placeholder' => Yii::t('person', 'Identification type'),
           ]),
       ],

    /*
       This code works!
    */

       [
           'attribute' => 'identification_type',
           'filter' => Arrai::t('app', TYPE_ID),
           'value'=> function($model){
                return Yii::t('app', TYPE_ID[$model->identification_type]);
            },
           'filterInputOptions' => [
                'class' => 'selectpicker',
                'data-style'=>"btn btn-primary btn-round",
                'title'=> "Sin seleccion",
           ],
        ],

    // other columns


]
```

And the following is the result html:

**`Result HTML`**

```php
<div class="form-group is-empty">
<select id="personsearch-identification_type" class="form-control" name="PersonSearch[identification_type]" 
    data-s2-options="s2options_6cc131ae"
    data-krajee-select2="select2_0ed9734f"
    style="display:none">
       <option value="">Tipo de identificación</option>
       <option value="CC">Citizenship card</option>
       <option value="CE">Foreigner ID</option>
       <option value="PAS">Passport</option>
       <option value="NIT">NIT</option>
</select>
<span class="material-input"></span></div>
```

In this result, a **`<span>`** tag is required to display the Select2. But it does not appear.

Comment: what does `Arrai::t('person',TYPE_ID)` outputs? is it an array or text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem What happens is that I had the advanced search enabled. And the select2 of the advanced search has the same ID as the GridView filter.

I just have to modify the ID name and it's ready.

```
[
    'attribute' => 'id_setting_person_identification_type',
    'value' => function($model){
        $type_identication = SettingPerson::getMapGroup('Tipo de identificación');
        return Yii::t('app', $type_identication[$model->id_setting_person_identification_type]);
    },
    'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
    'filter' => $type_identication, 
    'filterWidgetOptions' => [
        'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
    ],
    'filterInputOptions' => [
        'placeholder' => '-',
        'id' => 'id_setting_person_identification_type_gridview',
    ]
],
```

Comment: This the answer @muhammad-omer-aslam

Comment: good you solved it, that's why you should always add full code rather than selected parts

Answer (score 0):

Change your column configurations to the following for using select2, you are providing the text to the `data` option if I am not wrong `Arrai::t('person', TYPE_ID)` whereas it should be an array either hardcoded or from the database.

```
[
   'attribute' => 'identification_type',
   'value'=> function($model){
          return Yii::t('app', TYPE_ID[$model->identification_type]);
    },
    'filter' => Select2::widget([
         'model' => $searchModel,
         'attribute' => 'identification_type',
         'data' => ['1'=>'option1','2'=>'option2'],
         'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
         'hideSearch' => true,
         'pluginOptions' => [
               'allowClear' => true,
               'width' => 'resolve',
          ],
         'options' => [
                'placeholder' => Yii::t('person', 'Identification type'),
          ]
    ),
 ],
```

I am using hardcoded array you can update it according to your requirements, if your values for the dropdown should be coming from the database then you can replace the array with

```
yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(Model::find()->asArray()->all(),'id','name')
```

where `Model` should be replaced with your specific model name and `'id' , 'name'` should also be replace with valid column names.

Comment: Thanks @muhammad-omer-aslam, but I use `Arrai::t('person', TYPE_ID)` on create/update and It's works. Also, if I write the data as you did in the example, it does not work either.

Comment: the thing is if `Arrai::t('person', TYPE_ID)` returns and array as `name=>value` pairs then its ok , but you are saying that it does not work with the hardcoded array is strange **what exactly does not work** because i tested it at my end and it works ? @ArturoVerbelDeLeón